# Select Link on website after login with Excel 2013 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a link on a webpage after logging in with VBA in excel. So far my code successfully opens the website and logs on. However, no examples I've seen in the forums seem to work for actually opening the next link.

HTML Code from the site:

```
<td class="nrmlFnt nWrap">
    <a id="ctl00_wpm_ac_ac_rbk_ctl01_lnkBrokerageAccountName" oncontextmenu="return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$wpm$ac$ac$rbk$ctl01$lnkBrokerageAccountName','')">Retirement</a>    
    </td>
```

While the innertext and ID are unique, I've been unable to select them.

I am new to VBA and may not have been implementing some of the solutions to similar problems quite right. Below is my code:

```
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Private Sub btnUpdate_click()

 'Create Variables for web browsing
 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement 'Elements to search for: textboxes, buttons etc...
 Dim MyURL As String

 'Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium

 'Clear errors to prevent from stopping code
 On Error GoTo Err_Clear
 'Input Desired webpage login URL
 MyURL = "https://client.schwab.com/Login/SignOn/CustomerCenterLogin.aspx"

 Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer 'Creates new browser session
 MyBrowser.Silent = True 'Avoids Pop-ups
 MyBrowser.navigate MyURL 'Navigates to URL
 MyBrowser.Visible = True 'Opens browser window. Change to False to run w/o opening

 'Wait for web page to fully load
 Do
    DoEvents
 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

 Set HTMLdoc = MyBrowser.document
 'Enter Username:
 HTMLdoc.all.ctl00_WebPartManager1_CenterLogin_LoginUserControlId_txtLoginID.Value = "username"
 'Enter Password:
 HTMLdoc.all.txtpassword.Value = "password"

 'Click Login button on webpage:
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
 If MyHTML_Element.ID = "ctl00_WebPartManager1_CenterLogin_LoginUserControlId_btnLogin" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
 Next

 'Wait for web page to fully load
Do
    DoEvents
 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

 'Select Account to be displayed:
Set HTMLdoc = MyBrowser.document
Set e = HTMLdoc.getElementById("ctl00_wpm_ac_ac_rbk_ctl01_lnkBrokerageAccountName")
e.Click


 'Wait for web page to fully load
 Do
    DoEvents
 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

'Define Err_Clear Function:
Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If

End Sub
```

I feel this should be something pretty simple like the following, but it hasn't worked:

```
Set MyHTML_Element= MyBrowser.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_wpm_ac_ac_rbk_ctl01_lnkBrokerageAccountName").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
  MyHTML_Element.Click
```

I have also tried the following with no success:

```
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
 If MyHTML_Element.ID = "ctl00_wpm_ac_ac_rbk_ctl01_lnkBrokerageAccountName" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
 Next
```

The webpage loads, logs in and then... nothing happens.

Comment: Can you revise your Q to give us some code that is actually executable? What you've given so far is snippets that can't be run without context. Please show the rest of your code, or at least hte bare minimum required to allow someone else to attempt to *run* the code without having to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Also, please describe what you mean by "no success"? Do you get an error? If so, please indicate which line raises the error and what is the specific error message.

Comment: Alright I added my full code and when I run my code, it logs in and then nothing happens, but the macro keeps running.

Comment: If you know the element's `ID` value, why don't you use the `HTMLdoc.getElementByID`?  Then use a breakpoint to debug and ensure that this element is returned correctly.

Comment: Also, your use of `:` is technically not a *problem*, but it's very unconventional and makes for illegible code. Suggest to remove those colons and use new lines. In the grand scheme of things, legible code is more important than minimizing the number of "lines" it uses.  Cheers.

Comment: @DavidZemens: How do I see if the element is returned correctly? I am pretty new at VBA, this being my first macro. Everything I have so far has come from piecing together different tutorials on the web and reading forums. Also, how would you suggest then executing the link? Should my code look something like this?  `Set HTMLdoc = MyBrowser.document` then on the next line: 
   `HTMLdoc.getElementById ("ctl00_wpm_ac_ac_rbk_ctl01_lnkBrokerageAccountName")`

Comment: Google for how to debug VBA there is a really good resource on Chip Pearson's website that will explain how to step their code, use breakpoints, etc. You'll need to assign that element to a variable i.e, `Set e = HtmlDoc.getElementByID (...` and then look at e in the Locals window.

Comment: @DavidZemens Ok put the following in and while stepping through the code it worked!, but when just running the macro it no longer went to the final page `Set HTMLdoc = MyBrowser.document`  
`Set e = HTMLdoc.getElementById("ctl00_wpm_ac_ac_rbk_ctl01_lnkBrokerageAccountName")`  
`e.Click`

Comment: K. Then the problem seems like the page hasn't finished loading. Is this URL behind a password/login screen? If not I can tinker with it later tonight. ..

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, I login and then click this link. I thought my code waited for the page to finish loading before it went to the next step.  Isn't that what the readystate_complete does?

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to make sure that `.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` **and** `MyBrowser.Busy = False`

Comment: You could do like: `Do: Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = 4 And Not MyBrowser.Busy`

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work finally. I apparently needed the webpage to finish loading and the simple "READYSTATE_COMPLETE" didn't cut it. So I ended up with this to make sure the page fully loaded:

```
With MyBrowser
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
End With
```

And then I used the following code to select the link:

```
Set HTMLdoc = MyBrowser.document
Set e = HTMLdoc.getElementById("ctl00_wpm_ac_ac_rbk_ctl01_lnkBrokerageAccountName")
e.Click
```

It finally goes to the correct page! Now I just need to pull the correct data... easy right?